# C++ CloseHandle() before return

Tags: c++

When I use the CloseHandle at the end of my code, before return(0), do I have to call it too when I end the program in for example an if() before a return(1)?

For example:

```
if(example){
   var = 1
                 // CloseHandle() or not?
   return(1);
}
```

Comment: There's not much valid C++ here...

Comment: What handle are you closing? Is this the end of your program or just a single routine. More code would help! Also, where are your semicolons? :P

Comment: `CloseHandle` to be used when you have a handle on hands and you are responsible for closing. Here in this snippet you don't even have a handle.

Comment: It depends. *Where* are you returning from, for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't matter *where* your `return` or `exit` is written; if it results in the end of your program, you should free your resource with `CloseHandle`<sup>†</sup>.

<sup><sup>†</sup> I assume you refer to [`CloseHandle` as provided by the Windows API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724211%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It's not a C++ function.</sup>

Comment: Actually, if you are about to terminate the program, there's little to be gained from calls to `CloseHandle`. The OS will do it for you. But that's pretty pedantic. In reality it would be rare for you to find your self about to terminate the program and with some handles to be closed. So, yes, call `CloseHandle` on all the handles that you create.

Comment: Or create a wrapper class and put `::CloseHandle` in the destructor.